# Call the aliased command inside a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create an alias to a specific command with flags

```
arc diff --preview
```

I have created the following bash function

```
arc(){
if [ "$1" = "diff" ] && [ "$2" = "--preview" ] ; then
    echo -n "Message example? (y/n)? "
    read answer
    if [ "$answer" != "${answer#[Yy]}" ] ;then
    arc $@
    else
    echo No
    fi
else
  echo "$2"
fi
}
```

Unfortunately, after saying "yes", or entering a different command (e.g. `arc pull`)
I'm entering the same prompet `"Message example? (y/n)? "` because I'm again calling `arc`.
How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the same function again. If arc is a external command, then do `command arc $@`. This will avoid calling the function you defined, and calls the external executable found in the PATH.

```
arc(){
if [ "$1" = "diff" ] && [ "$2" = "--preview" ] ; then
    echo -n "Message example? (y/n)? "
    read answer
    if [ "$answer" != "${answer#[Yy]}" ] ;then
    command arc "$@"
    else
    echo No
    fi
else
  echo "$2"
fi
}
```